# Redcuers returning undefined in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a problem with my dispatch.
Somehow it returns undefined even tho when I loged value of the input i want to pass I got the correct value.

Here is my reducer.

```
case actionTypes.ADD_COMMENT:
        return {
            ...state,
            posts : [
                ...posts,
                {
                    comment : action.payload.comment,
                }
            ]

        }

export const addComment = (payload : any) => {
return {
    type: actionTypes.ADD_COMMENT,
    payload
}
}
```

And here is how i m passing the value to the dispatch.

```
 if (commentValue) {
                let commentVal = commentValue.value
                console.log('--------commentVal', commentVal);
                dispatch(actions.addComment({commentVal}))
            }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
dispatch(action.addComment({comment: commentVal}))
```

since you are accessing the `comment` property on the payload in your reducer

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Hi @NikaRoffy if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Sorry i was in rush yesterday and I forgot mark it , fixed it,have a great day and thank you for the help